# pass a function to a widget factory widget, without executing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm developing a jQuery widget in jQueryUI widget factory which needs a function to be passed to it as a parameter. the problem is that the passed function runs every time a new instance of widget is created. here is my code:

```
       $(function(){
            $('a').addrow({
                inputs:[
                    {
                        name:'loo',
                        type:'submit',
                        click:function(){alert(1);}
                    }
                ]
            })

        })

$.widget('namespace.addrow', {
    options: {
        inputs:[]
    },
    _create: function () {
       alert(2);
    }
})
```

as you see, I passed a anonymous function in `inputs` array, and `alert(1);` is executed right when document is ready.

Comment: sorry, I you explain again what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about jQueryUI widget factory, but if your anonymous function is getting execute, wrap it in another anonymous function like this:

```
click:function(){
  return (function(){
    alert(1);
  }) ;
}
```

That should work.

update:
Without using return:

```
click:function(){
  this.click = (function(){
    alert(1);
  }) ;
}
```

Comment: TNX for your answer ,But I have problem with `return` can you suggest another solution for Example : [jQuery dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)

Comment: Sure, can you be more specific about the problem with return?

Comment: I have update to another version not using return. Did that work?